# Jersey POST Api not working without content length

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, postman

I am facing issue in my Jersey POST API when i am not sending content-length from postman.

```
@Path(value = "/upload")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface FileUpload {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void upload(@Context final HttpServletRequest request,
            @Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")) @NotNull @FormDataParam("file") InputStream modelInputStream,
            @Parameter(hidden = true) @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition modelFileFormDataContentDisposition)
            throws IOException;
    }
```

> We know that by default postman is sending content-length (in hidden
> headers) but i am not sending it.

When i pass content-length, everything works fine. But when i am not passing it then i am giving below exception

> 2020-12-09 14:51:36.951 ERROR 27356 --- [nio-8082-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
> servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Unable to process parts as no
> multi-part configuration has been provided**  at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2769)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar:9.0.30]

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: clientConfig.setChunkedEncodingEnabled(false);   could you try setting it to false

Comment: What are you doing with the `HttpServletRequest`?

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I wanted to get the content length from request object so i am using `HttpServletRequest`

Answer (score 0):

allowCasualMultipartParsing="true"